configure FatFs for 256 page size
I am planning to port FatFs on the IS25LP064A flash drive to communicate with my STM32H573ii over SPI. The FreeRTOS is running on STM32H573ii.
According to the IS25LP064A datasheet, the maximum page size is 256 bytes. The total size of the flash drive is 8 Mbyte.
1] Could you help me set the following parameters in FatFs?
GET_SECTOR_COUNT = 32768 (8 Mbyte / 256 bytes)
GET_SECTOR_SIZE = 256
Do I need to set the value of FF_MIN_SS since my maximum page size is 256 bytes?
FF_MIN_SS = 256
2] As per the datasheet, the erase block size is 4 Kbyte.
GET_BLOCK_SIZE = 16 (4 Kbyte / 256 bytes)
So Could you help me to find out the values of above parameters?
